# Adding an orderer of new organisation in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

I have a RAFT setup of hyperledger fabric 1.4. I am trying to onboard a new organisation. I have created different sets of crypto materials using cryptogen tool for the new organisation and followed the steps mentioned in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html for onboarding of organisation. I am able to join the peer of the new organisation. How can I add the orderer of the new organisation to the existing network ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Did u foudn answer of your query? I also want to add orderer of same ORG and diffrent org

Comment: No, Still have the same issue